# Cosmos DB: How to detect request charges with LINQ queries

Tags: azure, linq, nosql, azure-cosmosdb

In Cosmos DB v3, I'm getting an `IOrderedQueryable<T>` using `GetItemLinqQueryable<T>`. This allows me to write custom queries. The problem is I'd like to track request charges whenever a query is materialized. How can this be accomplished?

When I execute methods like `ReadItemAsync`and `ExecuteStoredProcedureAsync`, the returned object has a `RequestCharge` property, but I need to detect charges with linq queries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the extension method `ToFeedIterator` on your `IOrderedQueryable`.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq;

var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyClass>()
    .Where(c => true)
    .ToFeedIterator();

while (query.HasMoreResults)
{
    var response = await query.ReadNextAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(response.RequestCharge);

    foreach (var myClassInstance in response)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

edit: if you need count or any aggregate function:

```
var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<MyClass>()
    .Where(c => true);
Response<int> x = await query.CountAsync();
Console.WriteLine(x.RequestCharge);
int count = x; // Autoboxing
```

You can find the full list of available extension functions on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos/src/Linq/CosmosLinqExtensions.cs).

Comment: Thanks. How would this work in the case of `Count()` instead of `Where()`? Can you update your answer with both?

Comment: `CountAsync` returns `Response<int>`, so you can use this. Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks. This works. Is there a difference (in terms of performance in the case of `CosmosDB`) between doing a `Where` clause followed by a `Count` as opposed to putting the predicate in the `Count`?

Comment: Yeah, if you use `Count(predicate)`, you will use the default linq extensions and do the count evaluation client side. `CountAsync` is server-side, so it is both faster and cheaper. See also https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/issues/589